# Raising 500 errors deliberately in Sinatra in order to test how they are handled

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra, rack

I want to write an RSpec test which verifies that, should a 500 error occur in my Sinatra-powered API, the error will be caught by a Sinatra `error` definition and returned to the client in a JSON format. That is, rather than returning some HTML error page, it returns JSON like this to conform with the rest of the API:

```
{
  success: "false",
  response: "Internal server error"
}
```

However, I'm unsure how to actually trigger a 500 error in my Sinatra app in order to test this behaviour with RSpec. I can't find a way to mock Sinatra routes, so currently my best idea is this route which deliberately causes a 500. This feels like a pretty dreadful solution:

```
get '/api/v1/testing/internal-server-error' do
  1 / 0
end
```

Is there a way to mock Sinatra routes so that I can have, say, `/`'s route handler block raise an exception, therefore triggering a 500? If not, is there some other way to deliberately cause a 500 error in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When facing a situation like this, what I usually do is separate concerns, and move logic outside of the Sinatra `get ...` block. Then, it is easy to stub it and make it raise an error.

For example, given this server code:

```
# server.rb
require 'sinatra'

class SomeModel
  def self.some_action
    "do what you need to do"
  end
end

get '/' do
  SomeModel.some_action
end
```

You can then use this code to have the model, or any other class/function you are using to actually generate the response, raise an error, using this spec:

```
# spec
describe '/' do
  context 'on error' do
    before do 
      allow(SomeModel).to receive(:some_action) { raise ArgumentError }
    end

    it 'errors gracefully' do
      get '/'
      expect(last_response.status).to eq 500
    end
  end
end
```

For completeness, here is a self contained file that can be tested to demonstrate this approach by running `rspec thisfile.rb`:

```
# thisfile.rb
require 'rack/test'
require 'rspec'
require 'sinatra'

# server

class SomeModel
  def self.some_action
    "do what you need to do"
  end
end

get '/' do
  SomeModel.some_action
end

# spec_helper

ENV['APP_ENV'] = 'test'

module RSpecMixin
  include Rack::Test::Methods
  def app() Sinatra::Application end
end

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.include RSpecMixin
end

# spec

describe '/' do
  context 'on error' do
    before do 
      allow(SomeModel).to receive(:some_action) { raise ArgumentError }
    end

    it 'errors gracefully' do
      get '/'
      expect(last_response.status).to eq 500
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `halt` method:

```rb
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  halt 500, {
    success: 'false',
    response: 'Internal server error'
  }.to_json
end
```

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't really what I'm asking - I know how to raise a 500 and return JSON in Sinatra. What I want to do is raise a 500 in a route which should normally never raise one, for testing purposes only, using RSpec or Rack::Test.